# Google Nearby change type on click

Tags: google-maps, custom-controls

I'm working on a project where I'd like to show the choosen event on google maps with some additional information. (ex. all gas stations radius 2km).
Google doesn't allow a nearby search with multiple types.

> Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored).

So for now I'd like to change the type (ex. gas_station or store) if I click to a custom button I added.
(used the google document example)

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4vql.jpg

**Question:**
Which is the best way to change the type and refresh the map with the new information?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to present you our solution.
We wrote a clear() and a showType() function, which will erase all markers and let the right ones appear on click. By the way we give the button a state class called "selected" for CSS styling.

We didn't find a solution to show both (washstation AND fuelstation).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var infowindow;
    var service;
    var eventLocation = {lat: <?= $arrCoordinates['latitude']?>, lng: <?= $arrCoordinates['longitude']?>};
    var markers = [];
    var wash = document.getElementById('wash'); //washbutton
    var fuel = document.getElementById('fuel'); //fuelstation button

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('eventmap'), {
            center: eventLocation,
            zoom: 13,
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        showType('gas_station');
        fuel.classList.add("selected");


        typeControl(map);
    }

    // Type control function
    function typeControl ( map ) {

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(fuel, 'click', function() {
            wash.classList.remove("selected");
            fuel.classList.remove("selected");
            clear()
            showType('gas_station')
            this.classList.add("selected");   
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(wash, 'click', function() {
            wash.classList.remove("selected");
            fuel.classList.remove("selected");
            clear()
            showType('car_wash')
            this.classList.add("selected");
        });
    }

    function showType(type) {    
        service.nearbySearch({
            location: eventLocation,
            radius: 10000,
            type: [type]
        }, callback);
    }
    function clear() {
        markers.forEach(marker => marker.setMap(null));
        markers = [];
    }

    function callback(results, status) {
        clear()
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                createMarker(results[i]);
            }
            createTuningEventMarker();
        }
    }

    function createTuningEventMarker(place) {
        var eventLocation = {lat: <?= $arrCoordinates['latitude']?>, lng: <?= $arrCoordinates['longitude']?>};
        var eventIcon = {
          url: 'https://www.foo.lol/img/icons/pin.svg',
          // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60, 60),
          // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(30,60)
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon:eventIcon,
            position: eventLocation
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        infowindow.setContent('<?= $event['name']?>');
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
    }

        function createMarker(place) {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });
        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(place.name + "<br>Adress: " + place.vicinity);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }

</script>
```